# Nativescript IOS 13 ui-listview component not rendered

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

Hi guys I'm having problem with listview component on IOS13
I tried updating to the latest version but that doesn't work

I fixed it by patching listview.ios.js, directly in node_modules
Like suggested from comment here:

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1160#issuecomment-542039004

And that is working fine but is there any to patch it differently ?

For example:

I tried creating new file **app-platform.ios.js**

and attaching missing methods to listview directly like:

```
const listview = require('nativescript-ui-listview');

listview.ListViewCell.prototype.systemLayoutSizeFittingSizeWithHorizontalFittingPriorityVerticalFittingPriority = function (targetSize, horizontalFittingPriority, verticalFittingPriority) {
    if (this.view && this.view.itemView && this.view.itemView.parent) {
        var owner = this.view.itemView.parent;
        owner._preparingCell = true;
        var dimensions = owner.layoutCell(this, undefined);
        owner._preparingCell = false;
        return CGSizeMake(view_1.layout.toDeviceIndependentPixels(dimensions.measuredWidth), view_1.layout.toDeviceIndependentPixels(dimensions.measuredHeight));
    }
    return targetSize;
};
```

But that creashes my app, I get cannot call method on undefined :/

Comment: Are you sure that your `package.json` reference `"nativescript-ui-listview": "^7.1.0",` or higher?

Comment: yes, and it wont render item rows, but also my tns-ios is on 4.0.1 and tns cli is on 5.4.2

Comment: What's the version of your `tns-core-modules`? Also whats the version of `nativescript-ui-core` in your package lock file?

Comment: Its not about the version if I edit directly listview.ios.js it is working, but how do I add those methods to prototype ?

Comment: It's about the version, because those specific lines of code were fixed in 7.x I guess. There could be compatibility issues if you are running lower version of tns runtime / core modules with higher version of UI packages. But if you are fine with patching it up, you could but you should know how & where.  I'm not sure where you found the above code but there are no reference of `ListViewCell` in the package. [Here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1160#issuecomment-545098260) is a code snippet which seem to work for your case, with older version of list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone still needs this, managed to solve it in you main.js path listview with this.

```
const application = require('application');


if (application.ios) {
    const view_1 = require("tns-core-modules/ui/core/view");
    const listView = require('nativescript-ui-listview');

    listView.ExtendedListViewCell.prototype.systemLayoutSizeFittingSizeWithHorizontalFittingPriorityVerticalFittingPriority = function (targetSize, horizontalFittingPriority, verticalFittingPriority) {
        if (this.view && this.view.itemView && this.view.itemView.parent) {
            var owner = this.view.itemView.parent;
            owner._preparingCell = true;
            var dimensions = owner.layoutCell(this, undefined);
            owner._preparingCell = false;
            return CGSizeMake(
                view_1.layout.toDeviceIndependentPixels(dimensions.measuredWidth),
                view_1.layout.toDeviceIndependentPixels(dimensions.measuredHeight)
            );
        }
        return targetSize;
    };
}
```